# Can't assemble android app: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/coreui/R$string; due to gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-glide, android-multidex

I'm having an issue with my android project. The issue seem to happen after updating `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta4'` and the gradle wrapper from `gradle-4.1-rc-1-all.zip` to `gradle-4.1-all.zip`

Multidex is already enabled, and was working as intended before.

When I run the app on the AVD, there is no problem at all, but when trying to `assemble` I have the following output

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/coreui/R$string;","sources":[{}],"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:\ncom.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/coreui/R$string;\n","tool":"Dex"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/coreui/R$string;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)","sources":[{}]}

:app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForGithubConfigDebug FAILED
:app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForGithubConfigDebug (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 1.204 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForGithubConfigDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/coreui/R$string;
```

I trie to check the dependencies, and only one version of core-ui (support-core-ui:26.0.1) is used (by supportv4, recyclerview and vector-drawable).

I trie to search the specific error, but couldn't find how to solve this.

Any way to solve this issue ?

**Edit: (solved)**

After all, it wasn't at all related to gradle. 
It was due to some issue with glide. [The issue is solved by adding @aar to the dependency.](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1972#issuecomment-304452188)

Answer (score 0):

Just Enable multidex as following:

```
android {    
  defaultConfig {
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
  }  
}
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Create one class like this

```
public class Multi_Dex extends Application {
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
}
```

Now in your manifest file add this

```
<application
    android:name=".Multi_Dex"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: just try one time **clear-rebuild-run** your project

Comment: Already did that. It didn't change anything. Still running never stopped working.

Comment: I solved the issue. It wasn't due to gradle, but due to glide. See my edit.